# How Do I Uninstall KDE Global Themes?

Tags: kde, themes

I installed a new Global Theme from :

```
System Settings - Global Theme - Get New Global Themes
```

I have now decided to go back to Breeze which I selected in the Global Theme window.

How do uninstall the new Global Theme that I no longer need?

There is no button or context menu to uninstall it.

System Info:

```
plasmashell 5.17.4
neon user "Bionic" - Build amd64 LIVE Binary 20190328-11:29
```

Comment: Please post the output of `plasmashell --version` and `cat /var/log/installer/media-info`.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting these directories helped me -

```
cd ~/.local/share/plasma
rm -r look-and-feel/
rm -r desktoptheme/
```